# How do I replace the obsolete NinjectWebServiceHostFactory and use NinjectServiceHostFactory

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, rest, ninject

I am trying to figure out how to expose my service as a REST service and not use the now obsolete NinjectWebServiceHostFactory.

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("MyService", new NinjectWebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(MyService)));
```

https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Wcf/blob/master/src/Ninject.Extensions.Wcf/WebServiceHost/NinjectWebServiceHostFactory.cs

The link above states" [Obsolete("Use NinjectServiceHostFactory and configure the Endpoint as REST service.")]"

So when I change it to the code below I can no longer send application/json requests to it. It complains and says it is expecting xml.

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("MyService", new NinjectServiceHostFactory(), typeof(MyService)));
```

How do I use the NinjectServiceHostFactory and create my route as a REST route.

Comment: More than 3 years and there is still no example available; https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Wcf/issues/34